# When using Apache Beam Python with GCP Dataflow, does it matter if you materialize the results of GroupByKey?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, generator, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

When using Apache Beam Python with GCP Dataflow, is there a downside to materializing the results of GroupByKey, say, to count the number of elements. For example:

```
def consume_group_by_key(element):
    season, fruits = element

    for fruit in fruits:
        yield f"{fruit} grows in {season}"


def consume_group_by_key_materialize(element):
    season, fruits = element

    num_fruits = len(list(fruits))
    print(f"There are {num_fruits} fruits grown in {season}")

    for fruit in fruits:
        yield f"{fruit} grows in {season}"


(
    pipeline
    | 'Create produce counts' >> beam.Create([
        ('spring', 'strawberry'),
        ('spring', 'carrot'),
        ('spring', 'eggplant'),
        ('spring', 'tomato'),
        ('summer', 'carrot'),
        ('summer', 'tomato'),
        ('summer', 'corn'),
        ('fall', 'carrot'),
        ('fall', 'tomato'),
        ('winter', 'eggplant'),
    ])
    | 'Group counts per produce' >> beam.GroupByKey()
    | beam.ParDo(consume_group_by_key_generator)
)
```

Are the grouped values, `fruits`, passed to my DoFn as a generator? Is there a performance penalty for using `consume_group_by_key_materialize` instead of `consume_group_by_key`? Or in other words materializing `fruits` via something like `len(list(fruits))`? If there are billions of fruits will this use up all my memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `len(list(fruits))` will materialize the entire list in memory before taking it's size, whereas your `consume_group_by_key` function iterates over the iterable once and (on distributed runners like Dataflow) does not require bringing the entire set of values into memory at once.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Is it safe to assume that distributed runners will provide you with a non-materialized iterable when consuming results of a GBK? Or another way to put it - is it always a good idea to avoid materialization of GBK results whenever possible?

Comment: Yes, that is generally best practice.